# bash script can't find file to source after conditional execution

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have a bash file that apparently works for others but not on my computer and I'm trying to figure it why. There is an `if` statement that checks if a file exists, and if it does, it will source it.

```
if [ -e "setenv.sh" ]; then 
    source setenv.sh
fi
```

The problem is, after the conditional execution it gives an error message that the file is not found. I have to go into every make script and use a absolute address for the file which is quite annoying. Theres a `#!/bin/bash` at the start of the script, and a `ls -l 'which sh'` gives `/bin/sh -> bash`.

Answer (score 0):

The description "works for others but not for me" points to a property outside of the script: the environment. In particular, the `source` (and its name-sake `.`) look for the file to source in the directories specified in `PATH` if the file name to source does not contain a slash. So to remedy, add `.` at the end of the `PATH` but be aware of the security consequences (for details ask your favorite search engine about dot and path).

In general it is bad script authoring to make assumptions about the contents of `PATH`. If you're a thorough software engineer, I'd contact the script writer and tell them about this bug. Yes, requiring `.` in `PATH` is a major bug.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the `setenv.sh` file in the same directory as the script you're running. Otherwise, as Jens pointed out, there is probably something wrong with your enviornment

Also, sourcing the file in a shell script will not affect your shell; just the subshell that it launches in. I assume since you're running a `setenv` script; that means you want to setup some kind of environment variables?